# Extract Text after first "-" Dash

Tags: oracle

I need to extract a substring from the beginning of string to 6 characters after the first dash, but stopping at a second dash.
Have:

```
X13-145222-2    
X13X1-125256    
X13DD1-045455-5
```

Wanted:

```
X13-145222
X13X1-125256
X13DD1-045455
```

Comment: " ... but stopping at a second dash ..." does this mean that the second dash can appear earlier than seven characters after the first dash?

Comment: Are you allowed to use computed columns?  Add one for the part of the string after the first hyphen, and then add one of thepart of teh remainder before the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want everything from the beginning of the string through the 6th character after the first hyphen?

This should work.  If it's possible to have a string with no hyphen, you'd need to make it more complex, but your examples imply there will always be at least one.

```
SUBSTR( string, 1, INSTR( string, '-') + 6 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_replace(string, '^((.*?)-(.*?))-.*$', '\1')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f99a0/1)